# Using for-loop inside thread won't match similar while-loop behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop

I just started to use threads in Java and I'm having issues with using for loop inside a thread.

When I am using a for loop inside the thread, from some reason I cannot see the outputs that I am sending to the screen.

When I am using the while loop it works like a charm.

The non-working code is the following:

```
public class ActionsToPerformInThread implements Runnable {
    private String string;

    public ActionsToPerformInThread(String string){
        this.string = string;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i == 10 ; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ActionsToPerformInThread("Hello"));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ActionsToPerformInThread("World"));
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

My question is: *why when I'm replacing the for-loop with while-loop and try to print the same output into the screen it does not work?*

I tried to debug it but it seems like the program stopped before getting to the part that its printing (There is not exception or error).

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (int i = 1; i == 10 ; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

did you mean?

```
i <= 10
```

i == 10 is 1 == 10. It is always false.

Answer (score 2):

You have a silly typo in your *for loop*:

```
for (int i = 1; i == 10 ; i++) {
    ...
}
```

should probably read as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A **typical** for-loop looks like this in Java :

```
   //pseudo code
    for( variable ; condition ; increment or decrement){
       //code to be executed...
    }
```

How it works :

1. First your `variable` is declared (can also be declared outside loop)
2. Then your `condition` is checked, if it's `true`, the code inside the loop is executed, otherwise the loop will not even be entered if it fails first time.
3. Then your `increment or decrement` is done, then step 2 happens again...
   this goes and on repeatedly until the `condition` is `false` then the loop exits.

In your case your `condition` is `i == 10`, this of course fails the first it's checked because `i` is still `1` and has not changed yet, as a result the code inside the for-loop is not even executed, the loop is not entered at all.

to fix this : You need to change your `condition` to `i <= 10`. By doing this you are telling the loop to "continue looping for as long as `i` is less than OR equals to 10."